transforming string of the form 100-50 to float 100+50 in Pandas Dataframe
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Rank  
1         1/1/2023       1               100-20     
1         1/1/2023       2               40-10       
2         11/9/2022      3               100-5     
3         17/4/2022      5               100-0     
3         17/4/2022      2               4-0     
4         1/3/2022       1               10-5        

where the data type of Rank is string. I want to extract the numbers in Rank and sum them, so the desire outcome looks like:
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Rank      New_column
1         1/1/2023       1               100-20    80 
1         1/1/2023       2               40-10     30  
2         11/9/2022      3               100-5     95
3         17/4/2022      5               100-0     100
3         17/4/2022      2               4-0       4
4         1/3/2022       1               10-5      5 


is the string always in the form A-B? can you have other operators?

One easy solution is to apply+pd.eval:
df['New_column'] = df['Rank'].apply(pd.eval)

Alternatively, extract both numbers and apply the subtraction:
df['New_column'] = (df['Rank'].str.extract(r'(\d+)-(\d+)')
                    .astype(int).pipe(lambda x: x[0]-x[1])
                   )

# or considering the sign and summing
df['New_column'] = (df['Rank'].str.extract(r'(\d+)(-\d+)')
                    .astype(int).sum(axis=1)
                   )

Output:
   Race_ID       Date  Student_ID    Rank  New_column
0        1   1/1/2023           1  100-20          80
1        1   1/1/2023           2   40-10          30
2        2  11/9/2022           3   100-5          95
3        3  17/4/2022           5   100-0         100
4        3  17/4/2022           2     4-0           4
5        4   1/3/2022           1    10-5           5

